# Problema com overflow-x e overflow-y no css

Tags: css

Boa tarde, tudo bem?

Eu preciso que uma table fique com scroll no eixo x, caso a largura da table seja maior que a largura do container. Se eu fizer isso, vai funcionar:

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Mas eu preciso que o overflow-y seja visible, pois no fim da tabela tem uma select, e quando eu abro a select ela aparece cortada.

Se eu colocar:

```
overflow-y: visible;
```

Ele coloca um scroll na vertical também.

Se alguém tiver alguma luz, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Olá! Testei no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahkayhat/) isso que você deseja fazer, e funcionou. Caso eu esteja errado, por favor esclareça mais sua dúvida.

Comment: Olá, tudo bem? Desculpe, esqueci de esclarecer algumas coisas... estou usando o [chosen select](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). A select padrão funciona normalmente mesmo, já o chosen não dá certo.

Comment: Aqui um exemplo da minha dúvida [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rogeralbi/ahkayhat/2/)

Comment: Esse foi o mais perto que cheguei por enquanto, dá uma olhada [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rogeralbi/88246m6c/1/) @Lioo

Comment: Certo, vi seu código e está fazendo exatamente o que você quer, não é? Não está mais cortando o `select`. Se não for isso, o que você deseja fazer?

Comment: Era isso mesmo, mas daí ele não respeita o scroll lateral, que eu precisava :/

Comment: Ah, então você deseja que o `select` **não acompanhe** o scroll lateral, é isso? Que suma da tela depois do scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Se foi o que entendi, você deseja que o `select` não acompanhe o scroll lateral.

Nesse seu caso, você pode fazer isso removendo o `position: absolute;` do estilo do `select`.

```js
$('#select1').chosen();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  /* colocar tudo dentro de um wrapper*/
  position: relative; /* com posicionamento relativo */
}
#container1{
  position: static; /* Adicionar position static no container com overflow */
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:visible;
}

table {
  width: 2000px; /* adicionar uma largura para mostrar o scroll no eixo x */
}

#select1_chosen {
  /* o chosen cria um #id-do-elemento_chosen */
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container1">
    <table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Teste</th>
          <th>Teste2</th>
       </tr> 
       </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Info</td>
          <td>info</td>
          <td>Info</td>
          <td>info</td>
          <td>Info</td>
          <td>info</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Info</td>
          <td>info</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
      </table>
      <select name="" id="select1">
          <option value="option 1">Op 1</option>
          <option value="option 2">Op 2</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: [Exemplo aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/88246m6c/3/)

Comment: Mas daí ele causa o scroll na vertical, e esse era o problema inicial.